# Scoring App that requires syncing data. Use AJAX, WebSockets or something else?

Tags: websocket, comet, long-polling, server-sent-events, webhooks

[Which technology to use]

I'm currently in the planning stages of creating a simple web app and unsure which technology to use to achieve best results.

App Details

- Sport scoring app used by 2 refs on either end of the field so I need to keep both the time and the scores in sync.
- The game lasts for 1 hour so data would need to be transferred throughout the entire time
- Both refs need to be able to update both teams score.
- The only data that would be transferred is the current time and 2 integers for each of the scores. Very small piece of data.

With all this in mind, what technology would be best in this case. I was originally going to use AJAX-polling to refresh the score every minute (guaranteed new data), but that interval is a bit to long I want the refs to be in sync as much as possibly.

I started looking a websockets (very new to me) and the [more I read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet), the more I saw that polling is considered a "hack", beyond the original purpose of AJAX. So im not sure if it's worth my time to implement AJAX polling or use websockets instead?

Which technology is best for my requirements? AJAX, Websockets or something else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a high-level framework which allows to write real-time webapp and focus on application's business logic itself. With low-level technologies, you may have to do something more to provide reliable full duplex connection as well as write the boilerplate code for common patterns.

As for the framework, if you are familiar with Java, you may want to try out [Cettia](http://cettia.io) I wrote. Otherwise, just google 'real-time framework' with your favorite server-side language.

Nevertheless, if you still want to deal with low-level technologies, I would like to recommend WebSocket which is designed for two-way communication.